# Implement an event binding so that when the user enters a Zip code on the form, it automatically fills the City based on the zip code entered

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Extremely new to Angular, but I am currently working to update my "city" field after inputting the 'zip' code. The getCityByZip function is to change to city based on the zip input on the form. The onZipChange should handle the onchange event. Any guidance or help would be much appreciated.

profile-editor.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  templateUrl: './profile-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-editor.component.css']
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent  {

  capstoneProposalForm = this.fb.group({
    contactName: ['', Validators.required],
    contactJob:  ['', Validators.required],
    contactEmail:  ['', Validators.required],
    contactPhone:  ['', Validators.required],
    orgName:  ['', Validators.required],
    orgAddress: this.fb.group ({
      street: ['', Validators.required],
      zip:  ['', Validators.required],
      city: [, Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
    orgWebsite: ['', Validators.required]
    

  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.capstoneProposalForm.value);
  }
 
  onZipChange(){
    let postal_code = this.capstoneProposalForm.get('orgAddress')!.get('zip')!.value;
    this.getCityByZip(postal_code);
        
  }

  getCityByZip(zip: string){

    if (zip=="30144" || "30152"){
      this.capstoneProposalForm.setValue({
        orgAddress: {
          city: 'Kennesaw'
        }
      })
    }
    else if (zip=="30060" || "30061"|| "30062"|| "30063" || "30064" || "30065" || "30066" || "30067" || "30068" || "30069"){
      this.capstoneProposalForm.patchValue({
        orgAddress: {
          city: 'Marietta'
        }
      })
    }
    else if (zip=="30188" || "30189"){
      this.capstoneProposalForm.patchValue({
        orgAddress: {
          city: 'Woodstock'
        }
      })
    }
}
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

Below is the section of my form with the event
profile-editor.component.html

```
<div formGroupName="orgAddress">
        <div>
        <label>Organization Address</label>
        </div>
        <label for="street">Street: </label>
        <input id="street" type="text" formControlName="street" required>

        <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
        <input id="zip" type="text" formControlName="zip"  (onchange)= "onZipChange()" required>
      
        <label for="city">City: </label>
        <input id="city" type="text" formControlName="city"  required >
      
        <label for="state">State: </label>
        <input id="state" type="text" formControlName="state" required>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="orgWebsite">Organization Website: </label> 
    <input id="orgWebsite" type="text" formControlName = "orgWebsite" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: This should be kind of working (your if conditions look pretty odd). What is wrong with this exactly (besides the fact it will always fill the city with `Kennesaw`)?

Comment: It never auto fills. And it’s supposed to auto fill Kennesaw if it’s the two zips associated. Or fill Marietta for the zips associated and so on.